# how to sense high frequency current and power sensing

Tags: current-measurement, power-measurement

Input

AC Voltage: 250V

Current:2A Max

Max Power out : 300W

**AC frequency : 4MHz**

Problem Statement is to measure power and sense current and alarm if exceeds certain limit

my approach :

step down AC voltage > feed to bridge rectifier > calculate its voltage

how to measure /  sense current ? as i have voltage, if i have current measured i can find power output

i am not seeing current sensing IC with bandwidth of 4MHz, even i doubt how transformers react to a 4Mhz input ?, even if i get a high BW current sense transformer how to measure current with of the shelf ICs(to construct an instumentation amp for I-V conversion)

first i want to simulate this approach on simulators like TINA or LT

kindly throw some light on approach to follow to measure high BW AC current sensing

Comment: Dude, this is a RF power monitor you're building here.  You might want to look into the techniques used in that domain...

Comment: Kindly help how to proceed